# Circular Inheritance after upgrade from Sitecore 9.3 to Sitecore 10.3

Tags: jss, upgrade, sxa-jss

We have upgraded Sitecore 9.3 to Sitecore 10.3 version. But after upgrade we are getting the Circular templates error for multiple templates. We have verified each and every templates's fields, inheritance,other section but we are not getting any clue.

ERRORS are

```
3280 08:10:27 ERROR Template trail: System/Templates/Sections/Tasks : System/Templates/Standard template : System/Templates/Sections/Layout : System/Templates/Standard template : System/Templates/Sections/Advanced : System/Templates/Standard template : System/Templates/Sections/Lifetime : System/Templates/Standard template : System/Templates/Sections/Help : System/Templates/Standard template : System/Templates/Sections/Appearance : System/Templates/Standard template : System/Templates/Sections/Layout : System/Templates/Standard template : System/Templates/Sections/Layout : System/Templates/Standard template : Feature/ClientProject/SiteMetaData/MetaData
3280 08:10:27 ERROR Circular template inheritance detected in 'Validators'
3280 08:10:27 ERROR This may be caused by explicitly assigned base id's or by the setting 'DefaultBaseTemplate' in web.config.
3280 08:10:27 ERROR Template trail: System/Templates/Sections/Validators : System/Templates/Standard template : System/Templates/Sections/Layout : System/Templates/Standard template : System/Templates/Sections/Advanced : System/Templates/Standard template : System/Templates/Sections/Lifetime : System/Templates/Standard template : System/Templates/Sections/Help : System/Templates/Standard template : System/Templates/Sections/Appearance : System/Templates/Standard template : System/Templates/Sections/Layout : System/Templates/Standard template : System/Templates/Sections/Layout : System/Templates/Standard template : Feature/ClientProject/SiteMetaData/MetaData
3280 08:10:27 ERROR Circular template inheritance detected in 'Workflow'
3280 08:10:27 ERROR This may be caused by explicitly assigned base id's or by the setting 'DefaultBaseTemplate' in web.config.
3280 08:10:27 ERROR Template trail: System/Templates/Sections/Workflow : System/Templates/Standard template : System/Templates/Sections/Layout : System/Templates/Standard template : System/Templates/Sections/Advanced : System/Templates/Standard template : System/Templates/Sections/Lifetime : System/Templates/Standard template : System/Templates/Sections/Help : System/Templates/Standard template : System/Templates/Sections/Appearance : System/Templates/Standard template : System/Templates/Sections/Layout : System/Templates/Standard template : System/Templates/Sections/Layout : System/Templates/Standard template : Feature/ClientProject/SiteMetaData/MetaData
3280 08:10:27 ERROR Circular template inheritance detected in 'Advanced'
3280 08:10:27 ERROR This may be caused by explicitly assigned base id's or by the setting 'DefaultBaseTemplate' in web.config.
3280 08:10:27 ERROR Template trail: System/Templates/Sections/Advanced : System/Templates/Standard template : System/Templates/Sections/Lifetime : System/Templates/Standard template : System/Templates/Sections/Advanced : System/Templates/Standard template : System/Templates/Sections/Lifetime : System/Templates/Standard template : System/Templates/Sections/Help : System/Templates/Standard template : System/Templates/Sections/Appearance : System/Templates/Standard template : System/Templates/Sections/Layout : System/Templates/Standard template : System/Templates/Sections/Layout : System/Templates/Standard template : Feature/ClientProject/SiteMetaData/MetaData
```

And other details are

- Current Version : 10.3 (initial version)
- Headless
- SXA
- ReactJS

Comment: Do you have any `DefaultBaseTemplate` in your config?

Comment: Yes. I have the DefaultBaseTemplate. and the id is of Standard Tempalte i.e. 
/sitecore/templates/System/Templates/Standard template

Comment: What base templates are assigned to Feature/ClientProject/SiteMetaData/MetaData? Assuming you have added that to the base templates of the standard template? The value of the __Base template field (for meta data template) should be set to {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}.